# How to get sum of array with "for" loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm a total newbie in `JavaScript`. I'm trying to learn it using programming experience in `Python`...

Let's say there is an array of integers `[2,3,4,5]`. I want to get sum of all items in it with `for` loop. In `Python` this gonna looks like

```
list_sum = 0
for i in [2,3,4,5]:
    list_sum += i
```

Result is `14`

But if I try same in `JavaScript`:

```
var listSum = 0;
for (i in [2,3,4,5])
{
    listSum += i;
}
```

This will return `00123`. Seems that item indexes concatenated in a string with initial `listSum` value. How to make code works as intended and to get sum of all array items as integer?

Comment: does for (var i in [2,3,4,5])  help?

Comment: `for-in` loop is not for iterating `array`..And yes, those are indexes("`keys`")

Comment: `var listSum = 0;
var input=[2,3,4,5];
for (var i in input)
{
    listSum += input[i];
}
console.log(listSum);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing wrong for loop syntax. check this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

```js
var listSum = 0;
var arr =  [2,3,4,5];
for (i=0;i<arr.length ; i++)
{
    listSum += arr[i];
}
document.write(listSum);
```

Comment: this works. By the way `for (i in arr)` works also